# Postgresql - Return a column resulting from join as single json column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, join

I have a many to many relationship between **users** and **roles** table (A typical usecase). They are related together using a **user_role** table. I execute the below query:

```
select 
    u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.middle_name,
    u.email_address, r.id, r.role_code
from 
master.user u
left join
master.user_role ur 
    on ur.user_id = u.id
    and ur.is_void = false
left join
master.role r
    on r.id = ur.role_id
    and r.is_void = false
where u.id = 7  and u.is_void = false
```

This results to

```
7;"Multi Role";"First";"Middle";"mult@gmail.com";1;"ST"
7;"Multi Role";"First";"Middle";"mult@gmail.com";2;"TC"
```

How do I aggregate the roles into one json or array column, such that it results to :

```
7;"Multi Role";"First";"Middle";"mult@gmail.com";[{id: 1, role_code : ST}, {id: 2, role_code: TC}]
```

Comment: Please fix your example: In your query you have "Multi Role" at the column of "first_name". I think this is not correct, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=16e30918d21419661009dd9bbb823671)

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    first_name, 
    last_name, 
    middle_name, 
    email_address, 
    jsonb_agg(
        jsonb_build_object('id', r_id, 'role_code', role_code)
    )
FROM 
    result_table
GROUP BY id, first_name, last_name, middle_name, email_address
```

1. Create a json object with `jsonb_build_object`, [Postgres JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)
2. Aggregate the json objects with `jsonb_agg`, [Postgres aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)

Of course you can use type `json` instead of `jsonb` as well; [Postgres JSON types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html)